# Internet Explorer - How to pass form data from one local html page to another local html page using a form?

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer

I have a form within an html page that has the action set to another html page.  Within Chrome, FF, and Safari, when I click on the first html page's Go button, I am taken to the second page with the URL containing the query string.

All browsers, with the exception of IE, show the query string in the URL when I submit the form.

How can I make the form submission show the query string in IE when working with local html files?  Any help would be appreciated.

HTML Form

```
<form  method="Get" action="destination.html">
   <input type="hidden" value="test" name="name" />    
   <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have `method="get"` as one of the form's attributes?

Comment: @rwacarter, thank you for the response.  Yes, I did use a get in my form.  Would additional code be needed?

Comment: @Porschiey, thank you for your response.  Both post and get on my version of IE 11 is not showing the query string.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't read completely that you wanted a query string out of it. POST would not be correct if you wanted to do this. I'd use a JavaScript/jQuery solution to do things like this, but that's my personal preference. Would you like to see how I'd do it?

Comment: @Porschiey, thanks for the response.  If jQuery is needed can you provide a hint and I will try to implement the hint?  Would you recommend using this method only for IE specific cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses jQuery/JavaScript, which may or may not be a little much for the simplicity of what you're trying to do, but if you already have jQuery on the page it's not too hard to try this methodology:

In your HTML `<input>`, add an Id.

```
<input type="hidden" id="field" name="field" value="showthis" />
```

In your script tags, try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-text').click(function () {
        var field = $('#myField').val();
        window.location.replace('destination.html?field=' + field);
    });
});
```